# Dynamically adding columns

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, exceljs

Is it possible to dynamically add columns to an excel table using exceljs?

I wrote this code:

```
        let workBook = new excel.Workbook();
        let workSheet = workBook.addWorksheet('report');

        workSheet.getRow(1).values = columns;
```

which creates columns with the names in the `columns` list.
But I don't know how to add `key`'s to items in this list.

In normal/static usage I create something like this:

```
        workSheet.columns = [
            {key: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {key: 'firstName', 'firstName'},
            {key: 'lastName', name: 'lastName'}
        ]
```

to map object from db to these `key`'s.

And the problem is, I don't know how to make a pair of key-values(name) where my key and values
would be the same as the object in my list - `columns`.

Does anybody have an idea/solution? Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Please have a look at this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52970298/creating-dynamic-number-of-columns-or-header-in-excel-in-nodejs-javascript). Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: @AhmerMH no, i see it